# How can Click on the first value ussing Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to click a bottton with value but i dont have value i need just click at the first I using this code but is not work

```
$("centre")[1].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your html I can't validate your problem, you are might missing a `.` and using `[1]` converts the object into a javascript object so you need to do this:

Also if you need to click on the first element then you need to use `0` not `1` because it's zero indexed meaning that the first element has index 0;

Since it's an ID you need to use `#` also then `:eq(0)` or `[0]` is irelevant because ID`s have to be unique.

`$("#centre").change();`

**demo**

```js
function getAppService(t) {
  console.log(t)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#centre").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="centre" name="centre" class="form-control-input" onchange="getAppService(this.value)">
  <option value="">Sélectionnez</option>
  <option value="8#3">Tangier</option>
</select>
```

Comment: <select id="centre" name="centre" class="form-control-input" onchange="getAppService(this.value)">
                    <option value="">Sélectionnez</option>
                                        <option value="8#3">Tangier</option

Comment: @aminolok Please include your html.

Comment: please help me if you can    the web site is this https://morocco.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php

Comment: i used but anything changed on the page :(

Comment: @aminolok First i can't find where you are using `$("#centre").change();` on your page, second you have alot of meta and titles in your body, those should be in your head section.